# SQLite COUNT and LEFT JOIN - how to combine?

Tags: sql, sqlite

There are two tables: one (P) that contains list of products, the other one (H) contains history of products consumed. Every product can be consumed 0 or more times. I need to build a query that will return all products from P along with number of times every product has been consumed, sorted by the times it's been consumed. Here is what I did:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Name, H.Date, COUNT(H.P_ID) as Count 
FROM P 
LEFT JOIN H 
  ON P.ID=H.P_ID  
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

This seems to work only if history table contains data, but if it does not - the result is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need a `group by` to get the counts that you need. You also need to apply an aggregate function to `H.Date`, otherwise it is not clear which date to pick:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Name, COUNT(H.P_ID) as Count, MAX(H.Date) as LastDate
FROM P 
LEFT JOIN H ON P.ID=H.P_ID
GROUP BY P.ID, P.Name
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

I picked `MAX(H.Date)` to produce the date of last consumption; if you need a different date from `H`, change the aggregating function.

I am not sure if sqlite lets you sort by alias; if it does not, replace

```
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

with

```
ORDER BY COUNT(H.P_ID) DESC
```

Comment: looks like sorting by alias works just fine, as well as the rest of your solution :) Thanks a lot!